# Does an online IDE that I could host on my server exist?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ide

I have a really fast windows server with tightVNC access. What I really need is an IDE that I can put on that server for my development work. I found a great online IDE at http://shiftedit.net/ but I can't download that and host it on my own server. Cloud9 was really interesting but it refuses to start unless it sits in a git repository.

All I need is an online IDE that supports syntax highlighting (And perhaps intellisense) for HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP that I can install on my server. It doesn't matter if it **must** be hosted on a linux or windows server because I can always put up a virtual one.

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Why does it need to be an online IDE when you have access through VNC and could use a normal one?

Comment: Because it requires that Java is installed on the client side, plus it's slower than hell even on fast connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the project formally known as bespin: http://ace.ajax.org/

Comment: This is still just a project. I was hoping there is an actual stable online IDE available somewhere

Comment: @Codemonkey It is now much more than that--see the [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/). Have you tried [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.com)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud9 with files which are placed on your server. Using git repository is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

SourceKit is an active spin-off of Bespin. See https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iieeldjdihkpoapgipfkeoddjckopgjg